# ffplay: Show timestamp (When paused)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

It's possible to show the timestamp with ffplay like this:

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=3:shadowy=3:fontsize=48:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh)" video.mp4
```

However, I would like to show the timestamp **only when the video is paused**.

Is this possible with ffplay? Additionally, I'd like the timestamp to show temporarily when seeking through the video, if possible.

Comment: Use `mpv` with a [Lua script](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/User-Scripts) (you may have to make your own).

Comment: Would prefer to use ffplay because I have it installed already and depend on ffmpeg for many other things. But I'll definitely consider installing mpv if I cannot accomplish the ffplay goal, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as ffplay doesn't send any event when paused and doesn't support drawing the text only on certain time.

You should use a different software like suggested (`mpv` for example), to have more control on what you render on top of the video.

An alternative is to also create a Python script that manages the video and displays the timestamp on top of it, with OpenCV for example.

Comment: I always used VLC because I assumed it was the best, but I hated how badly it always seeked through videos, at least on my system. So that's why I used FFPlay, it was nice and lightweight, and seeked without issue. Then I tried MPV, and I like it more than the features of VLC and FFPlay combined. Huge quality of life improvement, I have been making my own scripts. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're requesting but try `mpv` with `bookmarker.lua`.

After creating a config file, as described on [https://github.com/nimatrueway/mpv-[bookmark-lua-script][1]](https://github.com/nimatrueway/mpv-%5Bbookmark-lua-script%5D%5B1%5D), you'll be able to use the following shortcuts to save/retrieve timestamp bookmarks (saved in a `JSON` file):

```
Ctrl+1 script_message bookmark-set  1       #  `Ctrl+1` will "save current filePath and seekPos to bookmark #1 slot"
Alt+1  script_message bookmark-load 1       #  `Alt+2` will "restore current filePath and seekPos from bookmark #1 slot"
Alt+Ctrl+1  script_message bookmark-peek 1  #  `Alt+Ctrl+2` will give you a "peek of the filename, its immediate parent directory and seek-pos saved in the bookmark #1 slot"
Ctrl+2 script_message bookmark-set  2
Alt+2  script_message bookmark-load 2
Alt+Ctrl+2  script_message bookmark-peek 2
s script_message bookmark-update            # `s` will update last saved/restored bookmark
d script_message bookmark-peek-current      # `d` will peek last saved/restored bookmark (lastest saved/restored bookmark is only considered if current file is in the same directory as the bookmark file)
u script_message bookmark-set-undo          # `u` will undo/revert last save or update action
```